# Should I be accessing stuff within my fragment from the main activity it's being used in?

Tags: java, android

I'm not sure if this is bad practice or not, or what errors I could encounter in the future if I do this.

Basically I'm trying to switch two fragments with a `FragmentManager`, and I need to do this when I press a button that is *inside* my first fragment. I declare the fragment in the `main.xml` file like this:

```
<fragment
    class="com.example.MyApp.ButtonFragmentOne"
    android:id="@+id/button_fragment_one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout="@layout/button_fragment_one"
/>
```

I can access my button from my first fragment just fine in my `Main.java` file, but I'm not sure if I should do this or not.. Someone told me that it's a bad idea, but they couldn't really explain why. Should I be doing the onClick listener from my `Main.java` file, or inside the `ButtonFragmentOne.java` file? Does it matter at all?

Any documentation or help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is easy to solve. There is a documentation from [Google.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

To communicate between fragments you have to call your activity via an interface and the activity has to manage the switch between the fragments.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Is there a particular reason I should be using an interface or should I do what the other answer says with just making the fragmentTransation on the onClick of the button in the first fragment? I'm not sure which is better :X

Comment: For instance, I always communicate between fragments over the activity. Because the activity lifecycle is more consistent than the fragment lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

You can call below code on click of button of first fragment,

```
SecondFragment secFrag = new SecondFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,secFrag );
                    fragTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragTransaction.commit();
```

Official Documents :

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: So I don't need to use an interface? Just make the FragmentTransaction on the onClick for the button in the first fragment?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just replace/add another fragment in fragment container.